# Change firebase sibling value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase real-time database

[image]

I need to change sibling value using `symptomName` node.

I have tried the following:

```
  symptomssDatabase.child(symptomssDatabase.getKey()).child("count").setValue("0");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the value of `count` try the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Symptoms").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = ds.getKey();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Symptoms").child(key).child("count").setValue("0");
            }
        }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

You need to iterate to be able to get the `key` that is above child node `count`